# How to make Angular library's HttpInterceptor singleton while using on a lazy loaded shared module?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular library project let's call it *register-risk*. It has a `HttpInterceptor` named *HelloWorldInterceptor* which will intercept every `HttpRequest` and set `tenantId` on the header. The `tenantId` is set from the *register-risk* component (the main component of the library project).

***hello-world.interceptor.ts***

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HelloWorldInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private tenantId: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('>>> HelloWorldInterceptor constructor');
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('>>> intercept', { 'tenantId': this.tenantId });
    if (null == this.tenantId) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'hello-world': this.tenantId,
      },
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  setTenantId(tenantId: string) {
    this.tenantId = tenantId;
    console.log('>>> setTenantId', { 'tenantId': this.tenantId });
  }
}
```

***register-risk.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-risk',
  templateUrl: './register-risk.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register-risk.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RegisterRiskComponent implements OnChanges {
 @Input() riskRegistration: RiskRegistration;

 constructor(private helloWorldInterceptor: HelloWorldInterceptor)

 ngOnChanges(): void {
    const tenantId = this.riskRegistration?.tenantId;
    if (tenantId) {
      this.helloWorldInterceptor.setTenantId(tenantId);
    }
  }
}
```

The interceptor is provided from the module using `forRoot` and `forChild` static method. Though they are same.

***register-risk.module.ts***

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisterRiskComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    RegisterRiskComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    HelloWorldInterceptor
  ]
})
export class RegisterRiskModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<RegisterRiskModule> {
    console.log('>>> registerRiskModule forRoot');
    return {
      ngModule: RegisterRiskModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HelloWorldInterceptor,
        multi: true,
      }]
    };
  }

  static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders<RegisterRiskModule> {
    console.log('>>> registerRiskModule forChild');
    return {
      ngModule: RegisterRiskModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HelloWorldInterceptor,
        multi: true,
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

Then I tried to use the library from **another** Angular project's shared module (which will be lazy-loaded). Here is the corresponding code:

***shared.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RegisterRiskModule } from 'informatiq-register-risk';
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        RegisterRiskModule.forChild(),
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
import { RegisterRiskModule } from 'informatiq-register-risk';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        ...
        RegisterRiskModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now I think I have done something wrong in importing the library because it created multiple instances of the interceptor, and the `tenantId` value becomes `undefined` after set.

Here are some logs for ref:

```
>>> registerRiskModule forRoot
>>> HelloWorldInterceptor constructor
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> registerRiskModule forChild
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> HelloWorldInterceptor constructor
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> setTenantId {tenantId: 'aef2bb62-b3d2-44c6-b770-7f6e3aa1503e'}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
>>> intercept {tenantId: undefined}
```

Please also note that I don't want any main application `HttpRequest` to be intercepted by the *HelloWorldInterceptor*.

Comment: Since you do not want HelloWorldInterceptor to be the interceptor for your main application, I think you should avoid adding it to app module??